# Invalid Offset '0' error

Tags: php

i try to confider a php project it gives error like :

```
[RInvalidCollectionOffsetException, 0] 
Invalid Offset '0' 
@line 362 in file /xxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Classes/RCollection.php 

Debug Backtrace

#1 preferences.php:358 -- RCollection->offsetGet(...)
#2 config_language.php:40 -- Preferences->create_language_session(...)
#3 common.php:92 -- include(...)
#4 index.php:14 -- require_once(...)
```

code is :

```
public function offsetGet($Offset)
    {
        if (isset($this->Data[$Offset])) {
            return $this->Data[$Offset];
        }
        else {
            throw new RInvalidCollectionOffsetException($Offset);
        }
    }
```

there are many function

Comment: That's the code of the method. We need to see the code that _calls the method_, and therefore passes a zero...

Comment: It's the 11th time this week that such a question was asked. "Invalid Offset" my ass…

Comment: You method works perfectly. It is supposed to fail if `$Offset` equals to 0. This is a nice example of error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exception, you're passing a value of `0` to `offsetGet()`, but there isn't an offset of `0` in `$this->Data`.  The code seems to be doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing, as far as anybody here can tell (without knowing any runtime values).

```
public function offsetGet($Offset) // <--- receives a value of 0
{
    if (isset($this->Data[$Offset])) { // <--- evaluates to "false"
        return $this->Data[$Offset];
    }
    else {
        throw new RInvalidCollectionOffsetException($Offset); // <--- throws exception
    }
}
```